# Error Scaffolding with MvcMailer in MVC 4

Tags: mvcmailer

I'm trying to get [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) working in a new MVC 4 Beta project (created just for trying this out), using the latest version of NuGet.

I get to the step

> PM> Scaffold Mailer UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset

At which point I see the error message:

> <strike>Cannot resolve alias 'Scaffold' because it refers to term
>   'Invoke-Scaffolder', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function,
>   operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again. At
>   line:1 char:9
>   + Scaffold <<<<  Mailer UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Scaffold:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasNotResolvedException</strike>

**Update**: After installing MvcScaffolding (wasn't a NuGet prerequisite...), the error message for the same command changes to:

> Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that
>   accepts argument 'UserMailer'. At line:1 char:9
>   + Scaffold <<<<  Mailer UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Scaffolder], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I get this problem in MVC 3 as well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue, to fix it I updated the Scaffolding packages (T4 in one occasion, T4 + MVCScaffolding on another), and restarted VS.

```
update-package T4Scaffolding
```

**and / or**

```
Update-Package MvcScaffolding
```

remember to restart VS afterward.

Comment: I get further after installing MvcScaffolding (it was not installed... did I miss that in the docs?  Certainly wasn't a NuGet prereq), but now get the error `Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'UserMailer'.`  Any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind, found the follow-on issue (see my separate answer).

Comment: I was about to refer you to Eric's response before realizing you are the same person :) ....

After your comment I looked again at my code and realized that I've set Razor as my default scaffolder, guess i forgot to mention it.. Apologies.

Comment: Also see the issue on the MvcMailer site for further discussion: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/33

Comment: Updating T4Scaffolding and installing MvcScaffolding worked for me

Comment: I had to downgrade T4Scaffolding from version 1.0.6 to version 1.0.5. The package folder of version 1.0.6 did not contain the T4Scaffolding.dll file. After installing 1.0.5 the Scaffold cmdlet was available again.

Comment: For anyone attempting to get this working under Window 8 / VS2012, the new versions of MvcScaffolding 1.0.8 (https://nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding/) and T4Scaffolding 1.0.7 (https://nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding) solve the preview version of PowerShell issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked perfectly. The issue is resolved by Update-Package MvcScaffolding

Answer (score 6):

Segev's answer is correct as far as the original question goes.

It turns out that the scaffolding command *also* changed, causing the follow-on error.  The correct scaffolding command is:

**Scaffold Mailer.Razor UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset**

From

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/37

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues. The reason was I ignored the following prompt after T4Scaffolding upgrade:

> A different version of T4Scaffolding is already running in this instance of Visual Studio
>   Please restart Visual Studio to avoid unexpected behavior.
>   You won't be able to use scaffolding until you restart Visual Studio.

It was absolutely crucial to restart Visual Studio, then everything went on smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems updating the T4Scaffolding package.  It's because I had two T4Scaffolding folders in my Packages folder (T4Scaffolding.1.0.6 & T4Scaffolding.1.0.7).  I renamed the 1.0.6 to _T4Scaffolding1.0.6 and everything worked well after that.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is this:

1. Un-install **MvcMailer**.
2. Un-install **MvcScaffolding** and **T4Scaffolding**.
3. Set the correct Default Project in Package Manager Console.
4. Run this from command **Install-Package MvcScaffolding -Version 1.0.8-vs2013 -Pre** as mentioned by Scott himself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081028/scaffolding-controllers-with-repositories-in-mvc5-ef6-visualstudio-2013).
5. Install **MvcMailer** through Nuget.
6. Run this command **Scaffold Mailer.Razor UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset**

Comment: This is the only way I got it to work on Windows 8.1 Visual Studio 2013. AND You must run VS as administrator. As I found, you can't turn off UAC in Win 8.1 to avoid "run as administrator".

Comment: Yup, This is indeed the only way that worked for me too with Windows 8.1 and VS 2013.Thanks a lot for this help since I tried with almost all possibilities but nothing was working.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who still gets this issue after tried all above

You need to install Windows Management Framework 3.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34595)

T4Scaffolding.DLL is looking for System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0

I just did no more Scaffolding error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error also. "Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ..."
For me just closing VS12 and reopening fixed it.  Strange.